# Convert only one column from string to array in laravel 5

Tags: php, arrays, api, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I have a table `trend` in which i have one column `hashtags` to stored comma seprated values. I want to fetch trend data and want `hastags` column as array.

with the use of eloquent as below.

`$singleData = Trend::find($id);`

I am getting below as result for now.

```
{
    "status": "200",
    "isError": false,
    "data": {
        "message": "Trend found.",
        "singleData": {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "first trend",
            "start_date": "2018-11-16",
            "end_date": "2018-11-16",
            "slug": "first-trend",
            "hashtags": "first,trend,second",
            "created_by": 1,
            "status": false,
            "created_at": "2018-11-16 00:00:00",
            "updated_at": "2018-11-19 08:51:20"
        }
    }
}
```

And i want result as below

```
{
    "status": "200",
    "isError": false,
    "data": {
        "message": "Trend found.",
        "singleData": {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "first trend",
            "start_date": "2018-11-16",
            "end_date": "2018-11-16",
            "slug": "first-trend",
            "hashtags": [
                "first",
                "trend",
                "second"
                ],
            "created_by": 1,
            "status": false,
            "created_at": "2018-11-16 00:00:00",
            "updated_at": "2018-11-19 08:51:20"
        }
    }
}
```

I have got this result with the use of below code in my `TrendController`.

`$singleData->hashtags = explode(',', $singleData->hashtags);`

But i want any better way if possible to fetch using eloquent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators) for it

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Trend extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the trend's hashtag.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return string
     */
    public function getHashtagttribute($value)
    {
        return explode(',', $value);
    }
}
```

And now it will work like this:

```
$trend->hashtag; // array
```

OR If you are using it for API you can use [Eloquent: API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-resources)

You can use artisan command: php artisan make:resource Trend --collection
This command will create resource class. And you can modify data before it will be returned as a response.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class User extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'hashtags' => explode(',', $singleData->hashtags),
        ];
  }
}
```

And you can use it like:

```
use App\User;
use App\Http\Resources\Trend as TrendResource;

Route::get('/trend', function () {
    return new TrendResource(Trend::find(1));
});
```